# What are available pub/sub middlewares which support fine grained subscriptions and initial images?

Tags: communication

I'm looking for a middleware which would allow high performance pub/sub notifications with quite specific requirements:

- A) able to handle millions of separate items, addressed by string ids
- B) hundreds of client connections over TCP, possibly remote
- C) each client able to subscribe to distinct set of topics with single topic granularity; possibly 100k+ random topic subscriptions from single client
- D) each client sent only specific data it is subscribed to, no 'wide channels' and filtering only on client side
- E) high throughput in range of tens of thousands input ticks per second, millions updates per second outgoing to all clients in total
- F) getting last value (initial image) for item on subscription, without requesting 'fake update' from original publisher on separate channel causing it to propagate to all subscribers, or having it being sent out of the band and facing race conditions

Things which are NOT that important:

- persistence
- partitioning
- detail of communication between internal cluster nodes
- full updates versus only difference being sent
- specific item representation versus arbitrary byte arrays
- availability of CQ (continous queries) provided by middleware

Most available solutions fail on some of these requirements. JMS implementations(with topics) mostly fail A,C (scalability to millions of separate items) and F. Many high-performance data bus proposal fail at B (work only over multicast), C,D (broad multicast channels with optional inefficient filtering on clientside), F (no last value persisted, various types of hacky solutions to solve it). Redis looks quite close, but it fails at F and I have major doubts regarding E. TibcoRV fails at F as well, plus cheats a bit on D.

RMDS fulfills all above requirements, but it is proprietary, quite hard to setup maintain and imposes item representation which is quite painful. I'm looking for viable alternatives to it, giving more power, possibly at some cost of performance. Not sure how Coherence and Gemfire fares here - I think they might have issues with C (as they are more tailored for CQ types of requests) and E. ZeroMQ looks like it could be used to implement something like that, but they are very much tailored to common prefix filtering, which breaks C.

I have found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Distribution_Service which looks related, but it seems horribly overdesigned - not easy to understand what it really provides (I have a feeling it would require pages of non-trivial code to do most simple things on top of that) and what is the resulting performance of actual setup for my usecases.

(this is repost from stackexchange question, as I was told that softwarerecs is better forum for such kinds of questions)

Comment: Have you looked into [Redis](http://redis.io/) at all?

Comment: Yes - as I have mentioned, I have not found a way to have Redis transfer initial image for pub/sub topics (or to get proper notifications/subscriptions for normal storage).

Comment: I have done quick test with Redis for pub/sub, even forgetting problem of missing initial images and performance seems abysmal - I was able to get around 2500 messages per second with short messages (6-10 bytes keys, 10 bytes long contents), with Redis server taking 50% of cpu core (and all that on same machine, it would be probably considerably worse over even close network). Changing number of publishers makes it possible to go to around 4k/second. With multiple clients, total throughput (messages summed across all notified clients) is around 33k/s with 100% core consumption by redis server.